# Enqueue Styles to my WP Theme

Tags: php, css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am building out my first website theme and having trouble getting my CSS to port to the site and take hold. You can see my functions.php below for reference I have also attached a link to the site in which seems to only be display un-styled elements. Thanks

Link: 69375f29.ngrok.io

```html
<?php

  function abstract_theme_styles() {

    wp_enqueue_style('foundation_css', get_template_directory_uri().'css/foundation.css');
    wp_enqueue_style('foundation_min_css', get_template_directory_uri().'css/foundation.min.css');
    wp_enqueue_style('main_css', get_template_directory_uri().'/style.css');

  }

  add_action('wp_enque_scripts', 'abstract_theme_styles');

  function abstract_theme_js() {

    wp_enque_script('foundation_js',get_template_directory_uri().'js/foundation.js', array('jquery'), '', true);
    wp_enque_script('foundation_min_js',get_template_directory_uri().'js/foundation.min.js', array('jquery'), '', true);
    wp_enque_script('app_js',get_template_directory_uri().'js/app.js', array('jquery', 'foundation_js'), '', true);
  }

  add_action('wp_enque_scripts', 'abstract_theme_js');

?>
```

Comment: Check the spelling of wp_enqueue_script vs wp_enque_scripts. Looks like a misspelling error.

Comment: ahhh! thank you so much! as i am just starting off it still amazes me that those small errors can make or break a site.. cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I think that using the function **get_template_directory_uri()** you have to add de "/" at the end. The code would be like this:

```
<?php

  function abstract_theme_styles() {

    wp_enqueue_style('foundation_css', get_template_directory_uri().'/css/foundation.css');
    wp_enqueue_style('foundation_min_css', get_template_directory_uri().'/css/foundation.min.css');
    wp_enqueue_style('main_css', get_template_directory_uri().'/style.css');

  }

  add_action('wp_enque_scripts', 'abstract_theme_styles');

  function abstract_theme_js() {

    wp_enque_script('foundation_js',get_template_directory_uri().'/js/foundation.js', array('jquery'), '', true);
    wp_enque_script('foundation_min_js',get_template_directory_uri().'/js/foundation.min.js', array('jquery'), '', true);
    wp_enque_script('app_js',get_template_directory_uri().'/js/app.js', array('jquery', 'foundation_js'), '', true);
  }

  add_action('wp_enque_scripts', 'abstract_theme_js');

?>
```